# What is considered best practice when importing data in a 'pipeline'?

Tags: r

Let's say I have some sort of process that takes data from a CSV that is located on my local machine. This process will eventually need to be scheduled via some cron job. I need to import that data obviously and if I'm writing an automated script there are two main solutions for this.

1. Create a user defined function that includes the import statement in the body.

```
    import_data_and_clean <- function(full_path){
         data = read_csv(path)
         ....
    }
```

2. Create a dataset_builder.R file that not only imports the data, but also cleans and prepared the data for analysis.

```
data = read_csv(path)
....
```

My question pertains to which of these solutions was the reccomended way to do this in R?

Comment: I think this is opinion based and may get closed as off-topic (though it's a good question otherwise). My view for what it's worth is that if the script is run in isolation rather than being sourced from another R script, it doesn't really matter, but for reasons of maintenance and portability I would choose method 1. As an aside, it seems strange to want to know the idiomatic R way to this, when you are quite happy to use the non-idiomatic `=` for assignment instead of `<-` :p